# Programmatically change to another key in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, object, chart.js

I'm trying to prepare my data for a Chart.js, therefore I have to change object key programmatically. I found that this hardcoded version works. 
`

```
fetch('http://...)
        .then (results =>{
            return results.json();
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);


        var utplockadData = {
            datasets: [
            ]
        };


        for(var i=1; i<Object.keys(data[0][0]).length; i++){
            utplockadData.datasets[i] = {label: Object.keys(data[0][0])[i], data: [], pointRadius: 1 ,fill: false, borderColor: "black"};
        }
        console.log(utplockadData);



        for (var i=1; i<data[0].length; i++){
            utplockadData.datasets[1].data[i] = {x: data[0][i].timestamp, y: data[0][i].airTemperature};
            utplockadData.datasets[2].data[i] = {x: data[0][i].timestamp, y: data[0][i].heaterTemperature};
        }
        console.log(utplockadData);
})
```

**Expected result:**

```
datasets: Array(3)
1:
borderColor: "black"
data: Array(1441)
[1 … 100]
1: {x: "2019-05-01 00:01:00", y: 4.2}
2: {x: "2019-05-01 00:02:09", y: 4.1}
3: {x: "2019-05-01 00:03:00", y: 4.1}
4: {x: "2019-05-01 00:04:09", y: 4.1}...
```

But if I add an array with the addresses to the keys and change the loop, like this:

`var enArray = [data[0][i].airTemperature, data[0][i].heaterTemperature];`

```
for (var i=1; i<data[0].length; i++){
            utplockadData.datasets[1].data[i] = {x: data[0][i].timestamp, y: enArray[0]};
            utplockadData.datasets[2].data[i] = {x: data[0][i].timestamp, y: enArray[1]};

}
```

The result is this, all keys have the same value:

**Not expected result:**

```
datasets: Array(3)
1:
borderColor: "black"
data: Array(1441)
[1 … 100]
1: {x: "2019-05-01 00:01:00", y: 4.1}
2: {x: "2019-05-01 00:02:09", y: 4.1}
3: {x: "2019-05-01 00:03:00", y: 4.1}
4: {x: "2019-05-01 00:04:09", y: 4.1}
5: {x: "2019-05-01 00:05:00", y: 4.1}
6: {x: "2019-05-01 00:06:00", y: 4.1}
7: {x: "2019-05-01 00:07:00", y: 4.1}...
```

I don't know what is going on here. How can  I access values of airTemperature and heaterTemperature without adding them all to the for-loop?

**UPDATE:** 
Adding example data from backend.

```
[

    [
        {timestamp: '2019-05-01 01:38:00',
            airTemperature: 3.5,
            heaterTemperature: 2.6 },

        {timestamp: '2019-05-01 01:39:00',
            airTemperature: 3.5,
            heaterTemperature: 2.6 },
    ],

        "text"

]
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of data right when its fetched?

Comment: First of all, what is enArray? Second, your for loop is empty. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with the inputs and expected output in a JSON format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your enArray isn't what you think it is...

```
var enArray = [data[0][i].airTemperature, data[0][i].heaterTemperature];
```

As your `i` is a single value, your enArray will a single flat array with two values in it, i.e. `[4.1, 4.2]`. These are being used over and over again in your new loop.

If you're still having problems, I suggest stripping it back to the simplest example you can create as a codepen or similar. That alone will probably lead you to the solution, but if not it will make far more likely that someone else will be able to help.

Comment: Looks like i got it's value from the first for-loop. Changing var to let solves that. But it doesn't solve the problem as it fails to compile.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My backend returns different numbers of columns from the database according to the users choice. For example heaterTemperature is one column. It would be easy to hardcode all columns in the loop. In fact I have a working example of that, but I need a way to avoid hardcoding since the number of choices will be really large.

Comment: Sorry, I'm struggling to understand what you're trying to do. I suggest stripping it back to the simplest example you can create as a codepen or similar. That alone will probably lead you to the solution, but if not it will make far more likely that someone else will be able to help.

Comment: I followed your recommendation and was able find a solution. If anyone else ends up here, maybe with an unclear idea of what should be done, I recommend you to also minimize the problem in a Codepen. But first, take a break. :)